# Inject Row into Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to inject rows into a rowset object to avoid multiple inline selects.

So normally you do

```
$table = new Model_DbTable_Bug();
$select = $table->select(false);
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false).... and so on
```

This will return all the bugs as a Bug Rowset.
Problem is, that the bug table also has comments.
Instead of iterating through all the bugs and fire yet another select for each bug to the database via

```
$bug->findDependentRowset('Model_DbTable_BugComment', 'idBug');
```

I would like to assign the comments to the Bug object in

A) a single select OR 
B) just do a second select with all the comments and assign the selected rows into a bug specific "Comment" rowset and then inject it into a variable in the Bug object which then can be accessed while iterating through all the bugs without asking the db again.

I know for display reasons I could just do a single select, but I need the model version of things to work with them later on.

Comment: +1 ... i would do more if it would let me ... I have fought with this same thing.

Comment: when I encounter this I either let it do the iterative lookups or just sidestep the model and access the db natively... both of which are bad and wrong imho

Comment: Zend lets me join over other tables and still I receive the actual object with more columns... what I am missing is some addRow() on a rowset object which would tune it already...

Comment: This is where a proper mapper starts to shine. It is not a sin to join multiple data sources (read: tables) in a mapper to produce the exact entity object you need. You could then easily produce a bug() object and a bugWithComment() object or any you need. If you feel that Zend Framework is allowing or disallowing any particular action you need to reevaluate your particular situation as you are probably in your own way.